# Make @PostConstruct do only for first instance of StateLess EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I have a class of staleless EJB (not singleton!). I need one method to be called (load configuration) only once when first bean of this class is created. @PostConstruct solves half of my problem but it's executed for every bean. What is the most elegant way to solve such problem?

Comment: Is your method eligible to a static execution?

Comment: @Guy Bouallet Yes, but I need to put this method in superclass and to have ability to override it if it's necessary

Comment: what does the method do? fields initialization?

Comment: @Guy Bouallet No, it reads config file.

Comment: Whats the reason for not using a singleton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see tow options:

- Consider using a singleton object encapsulating the configuration data of your file and add a reference to it in your EJB.
- consider a creational design patterns. I think that the prototype pattern should fit your need but you may find other alternatives. Check this for details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern.

Answer (score 0):

you can force the container to instantiate the singleton instance during application initialization by using the @Startup annotation.

```
@Startup
public class StartupBean {

@PostConstruct
private void startup() { ... }

@PreDestroy
private void shutdown() { ... }
...
}
```